# Not enough memory in C++ : write to file instead, read data in when needed?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I'm developing a tool for wavelet image analysis and machine learning on Linux machines in C++. 
It is limited by the size of the images, the number of scales and their corresponding filters (up to 2048x2048 doubles) for each of N orientations as well as additional memory and processing overhead by a machine learning algorithm.

Unfortunately my skills of Linux system programming are shallow at best, 
so I'm currently using no swap but figure it should be possible somehow?

I'm required to keep the imaginary and real part of the 
filtered images of each scale and orientation, as well as the corresponding wavelets for reconstruction purposes. I keep them in memory for additional speed for small images.

Regarding the memory use: I already

- store everything no more than once,
- only what is needed,
- cut out any double entries or redundancy,
- pass by reference only,
- use pointers over temporary objects,
- free memory as soon as it is not required any more and
- limit the number of calculations to the absolute minimum.

As with most data processing tools, speed is at the essence. As long as there
is enough memory the tool is about 3x as fast compared to the same implementation in Matlab code.

But as soon as I'm out of memory nothing goes any more. Unfortunately most of the images I'm training the algorithm on are huge (raw data 4096x4096 double entries, after symmetric padding even larger), therefore I hit the ceiling quite often.

Would it be bad practise to temporarily write data that is not needed for the current calculation / processing step from memory to the disk?

- What approach / data format would be most suitable to do that?
- I was thinking of using rapidXML to read and write an XML to a binary file and then read out only the required data. Would this work?
- Is a memory-mapped file what I need? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

I'm aware that this will result in performance loss, but it is more important that the software runs smoothly and does not freeze.

**I know that there are libraries out there that can do wavelet image analysis, so please spare the "Why reinvent the wheel, just use XYZ instead". I'm using very specific wavelets, I'm required to do it myself and I'm not supposed to use external libraries.**

Comment: Forget about XML.  The most suitable data format for use as temporary storage is the same data format you are using internally -- you can store huge arrays of arithmetic types (including complex pairs) with `fread` and `fwrite`, or your OS platform-specific functions (which often allow you to give hints to the readahead cache)

Comment: Or use some neutral binary serialization format like XDR

Comment: You might want to use some indexed file library like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or perhaps use [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/). Do you know slightly in advance the memory access pattern (i.e. are you able at loop i to know the data needed at loop i+1 or i+2, or is it random enough to be upredicatable)?

Comment: BTW, this is typically a case where making your software a free software (and publish it e.g. on http://github.com/ ...) could help you a big lot.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt , I'd have to create and keep track of the outsourced files manually though, right?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I currently can't make my software public, at least not the core algorithm that is part of my thesis. It is also part of my memory problem, therefore leaving out my algorithm would render the rest of the software useless.  The memory access pattern could be predicted, but loading the data req. for the next steps into memory in advance might choke it, but it is a really good tip, I'll look into that!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch re databases: this sounds reasonable. Forgive my complete ignorance, but can they handle large data such as for example storing and reading a complex 2d double array with 4096x4096 entries?

Comment: Is your software 64 bit?

Comment: If your data are temporary data - alloc memory when needed - free when no more use, considere that kernel linux and swap do a quite good job. Don't try to write data in a file yourself. But very be carefull on how you parcour your image, line by line is a good choice, column by column is a very bad choice. If your algorithm need a column by column process, take time to check if you cannot change this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, writing data to the disk to save memory is bad practice.

There is usually no need to manually write your data to the disk to save memory, unless you are reaching the limits of what you can address (4GB on 32bit machines, much more in 64bit machines).

The reason for this is that the OS is already doing exactly the same thing. It is very possible that your own solution would be slower than what the OS is doing. Read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) if you are not familiar with the concept of paging and virtual memory.

Comment: Well, I have 8GB of RAM, and no leaks whatsoever (ran Valgrind against my code). As mentioned I also have no (obvious) redundancy, so I DO have a memory problem - not a problem accessing it. The only thing I could improve (as mentioned in my post) is to temporarily store data that is not needed for the current processing step on the disk or outside my application.

Comment: Sorry, I did not address your problem of running out of memory. Are you sure that your freeze is caused by running out of memory? If you use 64bit and have a swap partition that is large enough, the OS should start writing your data to the disk even before you run out of memory. The size of your physical memory has nothing to do with how much memory your application can address.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look into using mmap and munmap to bring the images (and temporary results) into your address space and discard them when you no longer need them. mmap allows you to map the content of a *file* directly in memory. no more fread/fwrite. Direct memory access. Writes to the memory region are written back to the file too and bringing back that intermediate state later on is no harder than redoing an mmap.

The big advantages are:

1. no encoding in a bloated format like XML
2. perfectly suitable for transient results such as matrices that are represented in contiguous memory regions.
3. Dead simple to implement.
4. Completely delegate to the OS the decision of when to swap in and out.

Comment: But then `madvise` is very important if you want to handle more data than your have RAM

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your fundamental problem, but: Are you sure you need to be doing everything in double precision?  You may not be able to use integer coefficient wavelets, but storing the image data itself in doubles is usually pretty wasteful.  Also, 4k images aren't very big ... I'm assuming you are actually using frames of some sort so have redundant entries, otherwise your numbers don't seem to add up (and are you storing them sparsely?) ... or maybe you are just using a large number at once.

As for "should I write to disk"?  This can help, particularly if you are getting a 4x increase (or more) by taking image data to double precision.  You can answer it for yourself though, just measure the time to load and compare to your compute time to see if this is worth pursuing.  The wavelet itself should be very cheap, so I'm guess you're mostly dominated by your learning algorithm.  In that case, go ahead and throw out original data or whatever until you need it again.